# How can I initialize a calendar with a non-Gregorian system in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, calendar, swift3

I'm trying to use non-Gregorian calendaring systems in Swift 3. This isn't working, for example, with a Hebrew calendar:

```
let calendar = Calendar.init( identifier: NSHebrewCalendar )
```

Admittedly, I'm not sure if this is the right syntax and NSHebrewCalendar is just a guess. I looked `Calendar` up in the Swift documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293308-init) and I can't find a list of identifiers. Does anyone know where to find the identifiers for the different calendaring systems and whether this is the correct way to initialize a calendar? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew)`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where to find the list of identifiers?